# Extracting a complex substring using regex with data from a string in python

Tags: python, regex, string

I have a string say

```
text = 'i have on 31-Dec-08 USD 5234765 which I gave it in the donation"
```

i tried :

```
pattern = r"^[\d]{2}.*,[\d]{3}$"
data = re.findall(pattern, text)

for s in data:
    print(s)
```

my desired output :

[31-Dec-08, USD, 5234765]

Comment: hi, help us help you and please elobarate what is the "complex substring" you want to extract.

Comment: To extract all the matches you need to do `data = re.findall(pattern, text).groups()`. What exactly are you trying to capture in your regular expression?

Comment: What are the rules here? Also, do you mean you need a list with three values? Well, for the time being, you may simply use `\d.*\d`. Some more "complex" pattern is `\b[A-Z]{3}\b|\b\d{1,2}-[a-zA-Z]{3}-\d{2}\b|\b\d+\b` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/hR5x2p/1))

Comment: @MustafaAydın I want to extract exactly the same output from the given string. I am trying to write the pattern whole day. but its very difficult for me as I am begiiner

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I want to print the same output comma separated from the given string. I tried using regex but I could not succeed.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew your code working but there are other numbers in the string that I am getting in the output too.

Comment: hey brother @WiktorStribiżew, I got it. thanks. you people are amazing

Comment: So, what worked for you?

Answer (score 0):

you can do it that way

```
import re

regex = r"(\w+-\w+-\w+)|([A-Z]{3})|(\d+)"

test_str = "i have on 31-Dec-08 USD 5234765 which I gave it in the donation"


matches = re.findall(regex, test_str)
temp = [_ for tupl in matches for _ in tupl if _]

print(temp) #['31-Dec-08', 'USD', '5234765']
```

- `\w` matches any word character (equivalent to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`)
- `+` matches the previous token between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
- `-`matches the character - literally (case sensitive)
- `[A-Z]{3}` matches the capital alphabet exactly 3 times.
- `\d` matches a digit (equivalent to `[0-9]`)